# jQuery finding "selector"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

following is my code

**HTML** :

```
<div id = "content" >
  <div class = "child" >Hello !! </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript** :

```
$(function() {
  $('#content .child').click(function() {
          //print the selected jQuery parameters
  });
});
```

I need to capture  parameters which I pass to `jQuery` function in above code,
  I want to print the output as `#content .child`.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own wrappers for click, focus, .. events that provide this functionality. Writing such a wrapper is fairly trivial. Here's one way:

```
jQuery.fn.addClick = function(fn) {
    var selector = this.selector; // capture the selector here
    this.click(function(event) { // write a wrapper for the click handler
        fn(event, selector); // call the user's handler and pass it the selector
    });
};
```

Your event handler function now gets two params instead of one. First is event, and the second is the selector that was used to bind this event.

```
$("#content .child").addClick(function(e, selector) {
    alert(selector); // "#content .child"
});
```

The advantage of wrapping it up with closures is that you can bind multiple click events to the same element with different selectors, and they will all work together.

[See an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GmYgF/).

Answer (score 3):

Normally you'd use `selector`, but in this context, `this` has no selector. You might use:

```
var div = $('#content .child');
div.click(function() {
    alert(div.selector);
});
```

Of course, that will show the same selector for each child, and not all that useful (maybe debugging). You can go simpler, mind you:

```
var selector = '#content .child';
$(selector).click(function() {
    alert(selector);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmuTv/

Comment: I can find the selector using a temp variable, but I want to find the selector with out using any variable

Comment: @Samurai Jack - I don't think that's possible within the event handler context. In fact, `selector` isn't that reliable anyway. Consider: `$('div').add('p')` - here you have a collection, but no selector.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Kobi's answer, it's not generally possible. It's kind of like asking "given the following loop how do I get the original array back again?"

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var a = array[i];
    alert( /* how do I get the original array given only 'a'? */ );
}
```

It's clear that in this case, you can't get the original array back given only `a`. But what might not be clear is that the same is true in your case as well.

This is because a call to `.click()` is essentially turned into a call to `.each()` and that's basically just a `for` loop around each of the matched elements. When you're looking at a single element in that collection, there's no way to get the original collection back again.